# Pinging servers in Python3

Tags: python

I have a python3 code that checks ip host access using  command ping
ip_host.txt contains ip: 212.19.24.234 and 212.19.24.219.
if I run code, I get following result:
['212.19.24.219\n - is down']
['212.19.24.234 - is up']

if I check using cmd-ping: 212.19.24.234 and 212.19.24.219 is up.
But I can not find an error in my code?
please help me

```
import subprocess
fp = open('ip_host.txt')
for ip in fp.readlines():
    response = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe",ip])
    response.wait()
    result = []
    if response.poll():
       res = (ip + " - is down")
    else:
       res = (ip + " - is up")

    result.append(res)
    print(result)
```

Comment: The biggest problem here is that `ip` has a trailing newline.

Comment: Besides that, you should look into using context managers, especially when working with file IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (the most important problem here) `ip` will hold lines from your file. This includes the newline character that you should remove using `str.strip`/`str.rstrip`.
2. You could also use `with...as` when opening files so you don't have to worry about closing them later.

```
with open('ip_host.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        res = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", line.rstrip()])
        ...
```

The only difference between `strip` and `rstrip` is that the latter removes only trailing whitespace. If you have leading whitespaces too, use `strip`.